# How to retrieve a static property from a generic derived class instance while having only an "object" in hand?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection

I have a WPF Control which is derived from a generic bases.
For example: IntegerUpDown from CommonNumericUpDown from NumericUpDown from UpDownBase.

UpDownBase have a static property declared as:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Value", typeof( T ), typeof( UpDownBase<T> ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( default( T ), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnValueChanged, OnCoerceValue, false, UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus ) );
```

I receive the following exception:
TypeLoadException (GenericArguments[0], 'System.Nullable`1[T]', on 'System.Nullable`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.)
when I try that (the exception happen while 'dynamic' is trying to get 'ValueProperty'):

```
var frameWorkElement = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
while (frameWorkElement != null)
{
    if (IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(typeof(UpDownBase<>), frameWorkElement.GetType())) // JaredPar StackOverfLow code
    {
        dynamic upDownT = frameWorkElement;
        DependencyProperty dp = upDownT.ValueProperty; // TypeLoadException
        if (dp != null)
        {
            be = frameWorkElement.GetBindingExpression(dp);

            if (be != null)
            {
                be.UpdateSource();
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    frameWorkElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(frameWorkElement) as FrameworkElement;
}
```

Why do I receive that exception and how can I get the appropriate dependencyProperty from my object in a generic fashion (no switch cases or similar) ?

**Update**

I modified JaredPar code to get the type:

```
    private static Type GetGenericBaseTypeOfType(Type generic, Type toCheck)
    {
        while (toCheck != null && toCheck != typeof(object))
        {
            var cur = toCheck.IsGenericType ? toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : toCheck;
            if (generic == cur)
            {
                return generic;
            }
            toCheck = toCheck.BaseType;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But still, I can't get the PropertyInfo to query its value.

```
    Type genericbaseType = GetGenericBaseTypeOfType(typeof (UpDownBase<>), frameWorkElement.GetType()); // JaredPar StackOverfLow code
                                {
                                    if (genericbaseType != null)
                                    {
                                        //UpDownBase<int>.ValueProperty  ok
// pi3 is null
                                        PropertyInfo pi3 = frameWorkElement.GetType().GetProperty("ValueProperty", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public);
// pi is null    
                                        PropertyInfo pi = genericbaseType.GetProperty("ValueProperty", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

**Update 2**

<strike>I accepted Sacrilege solution because he solved my biggest issue. I also think it is simply impossible to do what i'm trying. But don't try to make it works because it don't. I can't get the binding expression from the dependencyProperty I got from a maked GenericType and moreover from any generic I think, see following code and comments:</strike>

```
    Type upDownType = typeof(UpDownBase<>).MakeGenericType(frameWorkElement.GetType().BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);

    FieldInfo fi = upDownType.GetField("ValueProperty");
    if (fi != null)
    {
        var dp = fi.GetValue(null) as DependencyProperty;
        if (dp != null)
        {
            be = frameWorkElement.GetBindingExpression(dp); // Null
            if (be != null)
            {
                be.UpdateSource();
            }
            else
            {
// Next line be= null
                be = frameWorkElement.GetBindingExpression(UpDownBase<int>.ValueProperty); // Null
// Next line be = correct binding expression
                be = frameWorkElement.GetBindingExpression(IntegerUpDown.ValueProperty); // Ok valid bindingExpression
            }
```

Comment: Where is the exception coming from?

Comment: Hi SLaks, it is writen in comment in code. I will update my question to be more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @Slaks, the stack trace is "null".

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John Saunders, Thanks for the info, I appreciate. I will take care in the future. I used to do that :-s

Comment: Can you reorganize your code in such a way that T is already known at this point?

Comment: @Sacrilege, I wonder why you ask that? I want to be able to query the property in a generic fashion (as written in my question)? I modified JaredPar code and now it return a type. I now have the exact type  in hand of my generic base class. I'm trying to get the property from reflexion by I can't find how ???

Comment: Because it is easier if that was the case. Check out my answer though. I added some code that should work for you when you don't know T as well.

Comment: @Sacrilege, I was very positive when I saw your answer but it seems to not work ???

Comment: Check out my latest update regarding your update 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer were ok but has a default. The returned object was not exactly the one expected (seems like to be a copy of it). I think the key reside in the flag: "FlattenHierarchy".

The following code is working perfectly:

```
    var frameWorkElement = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
    while (frameWorkElement != null)
    {
        Type genericbaseType = GetGenericBaseTypeOfType(typeof(UpDownBase<>), frameWorkElement.GetType()); // JaredPar StackOverfLow code
        {
            if (genericbaseType != null)
            {
                FieldInfo fi = frameWorkElement.GetType().GetField("ValueProperty", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.SetField);
                if (fi != null)
                {
                    var dp = fi.GetValue(null) as DependencyProperty;
                    if (dp != null)
                    {
                        be = frameWorkElement.GetBindingExpression(dp); // Null if done like the other answer.
                        if (be != null)
                        {
                            be.UpdateSource();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        frameWorkElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(frameWorkElement) as FrameworkElement;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a static property on a specific instance. You can't do that in C#.

If you can arrange it so `T` is known at this point you can just call `UpDownBase<T>.ValueProperty` instead of `upDownT.ValueProperty`. Otherwise you'll have to resort to reflection to get `T` and then also to get the property.

This code should work to get the dp value without knowing `T` ahead of time.

```
Type upDownType = typeof(UpDownBase<>).MakeGenericType(upDownT.GetType().BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
DependencyProperty dp = (DependencyProperty)upDownType.GetField("ValueProperty").GetValue(null);
```

**In Reference to Update 3**

Well, that makes it a little easier then actually. You should be able to just get the depedndecy property from the concrete type then like this:

```
DependencyProperty dp = (DependencyProperty)frameWorkElement.GetType().GetField("ValueProperty").GetValue(null);
```

Comment: genericbaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0] (type returned from JaredPar modified code: weird type is: "UpDownBase`1")==> "Out of bounds array index" AND also: frameWorkElement.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] ==> "Out of bounds array index"

Comment: I don't have T or it seems to be a different one than the one declared?

Comment: I fixed one thing. My final specific class was not generic. I used your function using its BaseClass and I got the GenericType. But still, I can't query the property on that type which is defined as : "UpDownBase`1" ???

Comment: Oops, that's because it is actually a field. In my tests I mistakenly used a property. I've modified the code to call GetField instead of GetProperty.

Comment: Gotcha !!! Thanks ! Do you have an idea why it don't work on a "dynamic" ? By the way, sorry, I did push you in the wrong direction about property instead of field.

Comment: Originally you were trying to access the static field from the instance itself which you can't do in C# (you can in VB.NET). Now, you are accessing it from the type instead. You've probably used the IsNullOrEmpty method from the String class. You can't access that method from a string instance E.G. "myString".IsNullOrEmpty right? You have to call String.IsNullOrEmpty("myString"). It is the same for any static field/property/method on any class. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it make sense about static. You mainly solved my problem but honestly it still does not work (just for your info). I can get the dependencyProperty but it sounds to be a bad one (a duplicate of the original) but I can't get the BindingExpression from it. That is weird. Also you could see update 3 (coming soon about it). But I will keep your answer as the proper one because you answer my main concern (the main related to this question). Thanks a lot !